# Use of 'ing' after to

Tags: word-usage

"With our commitment to working towards finding alternatives for reducing environmental footprints....."
or should it be ".... to work towards..."
Got confused. Please guide me which one of these two would be the correct formation.

Comment: Please provide the full sentence you wish to correct.

Comment: Are you looking for a general rule on 'ing' following to?

Comment: I think *work* in this sentence would be a verb, while *working* would be a gerund functioning as a **noun**. There's a subtle difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, but have different structures, and pull out two slightly different meanings of *commit*.

> We commit to work towards ...

with a verb (*work*) can be paraphrased as *We commit that we will work ...*. It expresses a strong intention to do something.

> We commit to working towards ...

with a noun phrase (*working towards ...*) has a vaguer meaning, that might be paraphrased as *We will strongly support the process of working towards ...*. It is not necessarily committing that we ourselves will do the work (though we might), but expresses a strong intention that the process should happen.

Comment: Addicted to taking drugs, given to lying....why is the 'ing' form used instead of the infinitive one.? This may confuse a non native speaker.

Comment: @Josh61: there _is_ no general rule. Each verb or adjective has its own subcategorisation frame(s). _Addicted to_ and _given to_ have to be followed by a noun phrase, not a verb, so require the _-ing_ form. _Want to and _intend to_ must be followed by a verb phrase, so no _-ing_. _Committed to_ can take either, with a slightly different meaning, as I said.

Comment: I know, and I think that should be the answer.

Comment: In general I think that 'to' is followed by the 'ing' form when it is used as a preposition ( like from, for, at etc.) and not as a part  of the infinitive verb as in the examples shown above. This form will come natural with usage.

Comment: @Josh61: that's true, but not very helpful. There is no way for a learner to tell that _determined_ takes a _to_ infinitive, but _attracted_ takes _to_ with a noun phrase: these are just the properties of the particular words, which have to be learnt.

Comment: Thanks Colin & @Josh61 for your comments. That was useful.  Colin, now that I know that both the statements are correct with slight difference in meanings. According to your explanation, the first rephrased statement 'we commit that we will work' - to me the word 'will' brings with itself a bit of uncertainty and doesn't assure the reader about the future happenings. The sentence, 'commitment to working towards', seems to be a better fit for the usage I'm looking for. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @LP: I don't see that _we commit to working_ (or _we commit that we will work_) has any uncertainty, beyond the inevitable uncertainty of any statement about the future. To me it conveys a specific intention, which may not happen for some reason, but at this moment it is definitely what we intend. _commit to working towards_ is vaguer and less certain.

Comment: @Colin: Is it your experience or gut-feeling that says it is vaguer or less certain or you can substantiate that somehow. Just an inquiry to be more certain about your thoughts.

Comment: It's how I understand the phrases. I haven't an authority for my interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct, but 'working' gives the impression that you are *already* doing it, while 'work' gives the impression you *will do it* in the future.

Comment: Sorry, rogue click. Did not mean to downvote :-(

Comment: @Matt You should be able to reverse your downvote by clicking the downvote arrow again.

Answer (score -1):

We generally use 'commitment with 'ing' form' to talk about past, whereas , we use it without 'ing' to talk about present/future.

His commitment to teaching was so inspiring.
His commitment to teach will take him to success.

Not sure if there is a set rule for this.

Comment: I think OP is asking why, what is the rule according to which you use the 'ing' form instead of the infinitive. There is actually a list of nouns/adjectives that follow this rule.

Comment: "His commitment to teaching is so inspiring" is also valid. this is not a present/past issue.

Comment: I agree with @Matt, Veronica.  Take for eg., _I look forward to meeting you_. That is definitely a future situation.
I feel the statement you quoted, "His commitment to _teach_ will take him to success" sounds bit incorrect. Can anyone throw some light on it?